# HTACCESS file to redirect all pages to maintenance.php but not if /admin is accesses

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code which works perfectly for redirecting any page requested back to maintenance.php. However i would like the rule to ignore /admin as this is my admin panel that still needs to be accessed.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^/?(maintenance\.php|.*\.css|.*\.png|.*\.jpeg|.*\.svg|.*\.jpg|.*\.js)$ http://www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/maintenance.php [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule can do that:

```
RewriteRule !^/?(admin|maintenance\.php|.*\.css|.*\.png|.*\.jpeg|.*\.svg|.*\.jpg|.*\.js) http://www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/maintenance.php [R=302,L,NC]
```